# php mysql settings

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please fill in the root, db name, db user, MyPassword in the code below?
I cant seem to get it correct.

mysql16.000webhost.com
a8592246_dbname
a8592246_dbuser
MyPassword

---

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'practice');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .                   mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .     mysql_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{
echo “Successfully connected to your database…”;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just change the strings, `'localhost'`, `'practice'`, etc. with your *real* details.  What problem are you having?  What errors do you see?

Comment: Are you testing your code in the server or locally?

Comment: do I only have to fill in the 4 first lines (exept <?php ofc)
lets start with this question :)

Comment: Do you not understand what this code is doing?  Yes, you just need to update the `define()` statements.

Comment: This line will fail `echo “Successfully connected to your database…”;` - Curly quotes; beautiful, yet deadly.

Comment: Plus, you're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions, another fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions and they do not not mix together.

*Sidenote:* I use the same server myself, by the way. (*for testing purposes*).

Use this and fill in your own DB credentials.

**N.B.:**

On that server, you do not use `localhost` but `mysql16.000webhost.com` and your curly quotes `“` and `”` would have caused a `500` error, so I changed them to standard quotes `"`.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
else
    {
    echo "Successfully connected to your database";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The 4 first lines I got correct from the help from you guys, however I leave that script, was to much errors, I need to get in contact with a web developer, anyway, thanks for all the answers! :)

Comment: You're welcome. My (complete) answer will get you up and running (used like that with the rest of your DB credentials filled in) because I use the same server as you. @NightieeX - The other answers did not notice or fix the mix of SQL functions.

Comment: If you feel that my answer solved the problem (which I believe has), do mark as accepted. Cheers @NightieeX - That way it won't stay in the unanswered category.

Comment: You're quite welcome @NightieeX - Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
define('DB_NAME', "a8592246_dbname");
define('DB_USER',"a8592246_dbuser");
define('DB_PASSWORD',"MyPassword");

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .                   mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .     mysql_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{
echo “Successfully connected to your database…”;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');  //Normally this keep localhost
define('DB_NAME', 'a8592246_dbname');
define('DB_USER','a8592246_dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD','MyPassword');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .                   mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .     mysql_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{
echo “Successfully connected to your database…”;
}
?>
```